# carrierwave in production 404 not found on all carrier wave uploaded images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, http-status-code-404, carrierwave

Im using carrier wave to upload assets to my app they are stored in /public/uploads/photos/file/user_id/user_id.jpg to keep things simple.

Only in production I get 404 for all those images. 
I tried chmod 777 uploads -R * as last resort but that does not help.

Do I have to set something up I'm missing here to make it work, because these assets are outside the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

Had to set in /environments/production.rb

```
  config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: If I only Googled first, suffered later... =/